# Sitecore Federated Authentication's Authentication Challenge Nonce is null error

Tags: federated-authentication, owin

Whenever I use Sitecore's getsignonurl and signin, I am sucessfully authenticated everything works fine.

However, when I use the authentication challenge, User.Identity.IsAuthentication is false.
But, the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications shows as authenticated and and even the nonce is present.

[image]

[image]
The error logs shows:

```
Exception: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolInvalidNonceException
Message: IDX21323: RequireNonce is '[PII is hidden]'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. The nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'. Note if a 'nonce' is found it will be evaluated.
Source: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.ValidateNonce(OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext validationContext) in C:\agent2\_work\15\s\src\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect\OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.cs:line 639
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.ValidateAuthenticationResponse(OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext validationContext) in C:\agent2\_work\15\s\src\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect\OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.cs:line 264
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__1a.MoveNext()
```

Any Insights or suggestions?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Hi @Siddharth as you can see from the screenshot, AuthenticationType is ExternalCookie so I did this: var authenticated = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("ExternalCookie");